# How do I write a Java Application that reads docker container logs

Tags: java, docker

I have a Docker container running a game server on another computer, and on this system I have ***a simple Java application*** that I wish to simply take the "docker logs -f " and output that into ***JAVA APPLICATIONS*** system console.

Is there a simple, repeatable solution to this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can try the Docker Engine API, which has an API for getting container logs. I haven't used the Docker Engine API, so this is just a suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution I've found is to connect to the hosting machine via SSH with the JSch library, this lets me execute the command I wish to execute talking to the docker container and gives me a ByteArrayOutputStream to work with, perhaps not the most ideal but is functional

Edit: I've updated this to be more appropriate to my needs, appears to be working thus far. Although I'm having threading issues. Kinks to work out.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection projectZomboidServer = new Connection(USER_NAME, PASSWORD, MACHINE_HOST, MACHINE_PORT);
        ThreadController threadController = new ThreadController();
        String dockerCommand = "docker logs -f mason-project-zomboid-1";


        Runnable sshConnectionRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                executeDockerCommand( projectZomboidServer, dockerCommand, threadController);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Thread sshConnectionThread = new Thread(sshConnectionRunnable);
        sshConnectionThread.start();

}

public static void executeDockerCommand(Connection connection, String command, ThreadController controller) throws Exception {

        String username = connection.getUsername();
        String host = connection.getMachineHost();
        int port = connection.getMachinePort();
        String password = connection.getPassword();

        Session session = null;
        ChannelExec channel = null;

        try {
            session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();

            channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
            channel.connect();
            String cachedResponseStream = responseStream.toString();
            String output = "";
            while (channel.isConnected() && controller.isContThread()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (!cachedResponseStream.equalsIgnoreCase(responseStream.toString())) {
                    output = cachedResponseStream = responseStream.toString();
                    if (output.length() > OUTPUT_CHAR_LIMIT) {
                        output = cachedResponseStream.substring(cachedResponseStream.length() - OUTPUT_CHAR_LIMIT);
                    }
                    controller.setOutput(output);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```